# Website User Access Restriction based on a Role and a Variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

I would like to restrict the content that an user can access, but am unsure how to do it. This is a simplification of the website I am working on. The webpage should allow users to access content based on their role and their characteristic.

Roles are: Admins, Leaders, and Normal Users

Characteristic are: Red Team or Blue Team

1. Admins have access to everything
2. Leaders have access to leader pages and normal pages. Both have to correspond to their team color
3. Normal Users only have access to normal pages corresponding to their team
   color

The team an user is on is a variable stored in a database table. Users are able to switch teams, which changes if they are able to access Red or Blue pages.

With the "policy.RequireRole" in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization, I was able to restrict content by User Role.

However, I am unsure how to restrict content by team color, since team color is not a role. I also do not wish to hardcode variable checks, such as user.teamcolor = 'red'. Any ideas on what I could try, or existing things to check out?

---

Update:
Determined how to it by added a flags table to the database, where rows are colors and pages are columns. Boolean table used to set if access to page is allowed or not. Then created a custom requirement to check if the flag was true or not to pass. Startup code checks the role of user and the custom requirement. *Additional code was added to get the team color claim value of the user and search for the associated row

Links to reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0
https://github.com/eaardal/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop

Comment: "do not wish to hardcode variable checks, such as user.teamcolor = 'red'" , Could you show us some code that you've tried and explain how hardcode  variable checks you do not wish about it and we'll be better able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you just create a custom Access control like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Method,AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class AccessControlAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly TeamColor[] _colors;
    public AccessControlAttribute(params TeamColor[] colors)
    {
        _colors= colors;
    }

    public TeamColor[] Colors => _colors;
}
```

Then enforce it like this:

```
public sealed class ColorAccessControlFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    
    public ColorAccessControlFilterAttribute (IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userService));
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var accessControlAttribute = GetAttribute<AccessControlAttribute>(actionContext);

        if (accessControlAttribute == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var user = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

        var color = _userService.GetUserColor(user.UserID());

        if (color!= null)
        {
            var exist = accessControlAttribute.Colors.Contains(color);
            if(exist){return;}
        }

        actionContext.Response = actionContext
                                    .Request
                                    .CreateErrorResponse(
                                        HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
                                        "You do not have the required access control to view this resource."
                                    );
    }

    private T GetAttribute<T>(HttpActionContext actionContext) where T : Attribute
    {
        var att =
            actionContext.ActionDescriptor?.GetCustomAttributes<T>()?.FirstOrDefault() ??
            actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor?.GetCustomAttributes<T>()?.FirstOrDefault();

        return att;
    }
}
```